# How to access property placeholder defined in a domain project (Mule)?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, property-placeholder

I put a property placeholder in my domain project, Project A. However, I cannot access the property placeholder from Project B (dependent on Project A).

Project B returns the correct response when I directly put the property placeholder in Project B's global.xml. However, Project B does not return the correct response when I put the property placeholder in Project A's mule-domain-config.xml.

I expect Project B to successfully pull the property placeholder from Project A, but the actual output is that Project B is NOT successfully pulling the property placeholder from Project A.

[Using Mule 3.8 with Anypoint Studio 6.4.4]

Comment: Which version of Mule are you using?

Comment: Mule 3.8 using Anypoint Studio 6.4.4. Let me update the question. Thank you!